# PostgreSQL composing complex query string

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQLwith VB.NET/ODBC and have to construct a bit complex query string.
This is simplified version:

> SELECT dtbl_id, idx, name, meas, code, year FROM mytable 
>    WHERE name ILIKE 'nemo%' <- edited
>    AND (dtbl_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9999)
>    OR (dtbl_id BETWEEN 15000 AND 19999) ORDER BY name

I also try:

> AND (dtbl_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9999)
>     AND (dtbl_id BETWEEN 15000 AND 19999) ORDER BY name

Where I try to get names starting with "nemo" but only if they have indexes between 1 and 9999 and indexes between 15000 AND 19999.
In both cases I dont get desired result (if any).

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT dtbl_id, idx, name, meas, code, year 
FROM mytable 
WHERE name ILIKE '%nemo'
AND ((dtbl_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9999)
     OR (dtbl_id BETWEEN 15000 AND 19999))
ORDER BY name
```

Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE).

The mistake - `OR` has lower priority then `AND`. So, your first `WHERE` clause reads like:

```
WHERE (name ILIKE '%nemo'  AND dtbl_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9999)
   OR (dtbl_id BETWEEN 15000 AND 19999)
```

Another mistake (as pointed out by Edmund) - to get names **starting** with `nemo` you need `ILIKE 'nemo%'`.

Comment: OK, I have workable program with choosing 'from beginning' or "inside" so this is more typo than a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that "starting with nemo" is best obtained using the condition `name ILIKE 'nemo%'` -- note that the `%` wildcard is at the end.  Putting it at the start searches for names *ending with nemo*!

The second issue is the precedence of `OR` and `AND` operators, as pointed out by Igor.  Put brackets around the second two clauses as he shows.

Comment: Sorry, that becomes during simplifying an example for show here.